# Javascript function run with drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, menu, argument-passing

I have a drop down list that I want to pass an argument (color) to a function when something is selected. I have used Javascript a little in the past, but am not entirely sure how to do this. I have the javascript running in an external file. Ultimately I want the drop down menu to change to the color selected in the menu. Thanks in advance for your help.

HTML code

```
 <div id="Color_drop_menu">

 <form>
 <select id=Color1 onchange="Color1Change()">
    <option> </option>
    <option> "Black" </option>
    <option> "Brown" </option>
    <option> "Red" </option>
    <option> "Orange" </option>
    <option> "Yellow" </option>
    <option> "Green" </option>
    <option> "Blue" </option>
    <option> "Violet"</option>
    <option> "Grey" </option>
    <option> "White" </option>
    <option> "Gold" </option>
    <option> "Silver" </option>
</select>
</form>

</div>
```

Javascript code

```
function Color1Change(){
      console.log("Hello World"); //this prints Hello World
}
```

Comment: you should give your option tags a "value" as in <option value="Black">Black</option>... this allows your to get the "value" from the answers below for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Color1Change(x) {
    var color = x.options[x.selectedIndex].innerHTML.replace(/\"/g, '');
    document.getElementById('Color_drop_menu').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

and change your select element to: `<select id=Color1 onchange="Color1Change(this)">`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UmexV/)**

Comment: Thanks that is working great!! Is there a way to change the actual dropdown menu so that it is blue/red... instead of the background?

Comment: Sure, just change the second line in the function to `document.getElementById('Color1').style.backgroundColor = color;`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UmexV/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id=Color1 onchange="Color1Change(this)">
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
   function Color1Change(option){
      console.log(option.value); //this prints the text of your options if no value attribute is set.
}
</script>
```